# Blazor WebAssembly Visual Studio Debugger Issues

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, progressive-web-apps, blazor, webassembly

I've created a clean Blazor PWA project.  Less than half the time when I try to run it with the debugger it doesn't launch properly.  Half the time would actually be an improvement!

If try to launch with the debugger (F5 or Debug/Start Debugging), a new browser window is opened with "about:blank" as the URL.  After maybe a minute "localhost:xxxx" shows as the URL.....but the "Loading..." message does not appear.

If I run without the debugger (Ctrl+F5 or Debug/Start Without Debugging), the PWA launches like it should.  I can debug in the browser, but it isn't as smooth as when I can use Visual Studio.

Have tried using IIS Express and Project....Chrome, Edge, Edge Dev.

Am using Visual Studio v16.7.2.  Have reproduced a few times with clean projects.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to [ask]. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

I don´t know exactly about PWAs, but I have the same problem with the standard Blazor WebAssembly when launching the web app with the debugger. What helps in my case is opening the browser console with Ctrl + Shift + I, this seems to kickstart the application.

Comment: Interesting.....I tried it and it worked.  Hopefully it continues to work.  Given that is isn't very intuitive, how did you stumble on it?

Comment: Due to my lack of knowledge in the web world I always have the console open to see all the messages in it. Often if I forgot to open the console, the page wouldn´t load and left in the about:blank state. Only after I launched the console, a connection to localhost was visible.

Comment: I've been using that trick for a couple days now and it seems to work.  At worst I've had to open the console window twice.  I've personally used F12....just a tid-bit for someone who stumbles on this thread.

Now....if only MS would improve the object inspection I think we'd really be cooking.

Comment: Just for completeness -- 16.8.0 and later have correct the issue.  The .Net 5 release has improved life a good bit.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and simple followed these steps and solved my issue

1. Close all the browsers instance
2. Delete file /.vs/{projectName}/config/debuggerConfiguration-{guid}.json