# ASP.Net Core - debbuger starts Chrome, but doesn't go to application URL

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, blazor

After enabling "Windows Authentication" and disabling "Anonymous Authentication", when I try to debug my application, a new Chrome window opens, but it stays on "about:blank" and doesn't redirect to my application URL. It works normally on Firefox. It also works fine after I disable "Windows Authentication" and enable "Anonymous Authentication". When  I "Run without debugging" it also works correctly. The debugging doesn't stop when I close the browser and vice versa.
I am creating ASP.Net Core hosted Blazor WebAssembly application.

Here is my `launchSettings.json`:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51213",
      "sslPort": 44322
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}"
    },
    "AccessManager.Server": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem only occurs when I'm using the "IIS Express" profile. It works fine when I use "AccessManager.Server" profile.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue (already answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63679708/blazor-webassembly-visual-studio-debugger-issues/63682035#63682035)), a simple `Ctrl + Shift + I` triggers the page to load in my case.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work for me. After opening a console nothing changes and the page is still on "about:blank". There are also no messages in the console.